# Is calling co_spawn on the same io_context instance from different threads safe, and does it guarantee execution on the same thread?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I am working on a project that leverages boost::asio::io_context across different threads, and specifically, I want to use co_spawn to initiate coroutines. Here's a simplified code snippet:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <thread>

boost::asio::awaitable<void> my_coroutine() { /* ... */ }

void worker_thread(boost::asio::io_context& io)
{
  boost::asio::co_spawn(io, my_coroutine, boost::asio::detached);
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_context io;
  std::thread main_thread([&io](){ io.run(); });
  std::thread worker_thread(worker_thread, std::ref(io));
  main_thread.join();
  worker_thread.join();
  return 0;
}
```

I have two questions that I'm unsure about:

1. Is this safe? Can I be certain that this code is free from concurrent access issues if the io_context is used across different threads in this manner?
2. Does it guarantee execution on the same thread? Is there any guarantee that the coroutine launched by co_spawn will run on the same thread as the io_context, or is there a risk that it may be invoked on a different thread?

Answer (score 0):

---

> **Q.** *Is this safe?*

Yes. `io_context` is thread-safe: [doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html#:%7E:text=Thread%20Safety,use%20a%20single%20object%20concurrently.) and [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context.thread_safety):

> Distinct objects: Safe.
>
> Shared objects: Safe, with the specific exceptions of the restart()
> and notify_fork() functions. Calling restart() while there are
> unfinished run(), run_one(), run_for(), run_until(), poll() or
> poll_one() calls results in undefined behaviour. The notify_fork()
> function should not be called while any io_context function, or any
> function on an I/O object that is associated with the io_context, is
> being called in another thread.

---

> **Q.** *Can I be certain that this code is free from concurrent access issues if the io_context is used across different threads in this manner?*

It depends on what you're sharing. Since that is in no way related to Asio, I'm going to answer with "yes" again, like before. You're responsible for your own code, obviously.

---

> **Q.** Does it guarantee execution on the same thread?

It is unclear what thread you mean, because your example has three! I'm assuming you mean the `main_thread` instance (not the `main` thread, ironically), where you run the `io_context`...

---

> **Q.** Is there any guarantee that the coroutine launched by `co_spawn` will run on the same thread as the `io_context`, [or is there a risk that it may be invoked on a different thread?]

Yes. This is guaranteed. The only thing that **doesn't** run on that thread is your own `worker_thread` which *initiates* the coroutine on a third thread. But after the initial suspension all resumes are guaranteed to be on a service thread, i.e. the `main_thread` instance in your example.

The relevant documentation excerpt: [*"Asynchronous completion handlers will only be called from threads that are currently calling `io_context::run()`"*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html#:%7E:text=Asynchronous%20completion%20handlers%20will%20only%20be%20called%20from%20threads%20that%20are%20currently%20calling%20io_context%3A%3Arun())